# can someone help me, i am stack in trying to send mail from the localhost by smtp(laravel)

Tags: laravel

i keep getting this error

> Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.7.0 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError x4sm22694588pfi.202 - gsmtp "

Comment: Are your SMTP credentials correct??? you can try mailtrap for testing: https://mailtrap.io/pricing

Comment: Yes I am sure to help you to send mail. Please share your  some code of .env file

Comment: Did you take a look at the URL in that message?

Answer (score 0):

Setup your .env like below

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=your_domain
MAIL_PASSWORD="your_password"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

For using Gmail account as SMTP you must turn on less secure app settings in your Gmail account here is https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Then do

After that execute this command

```
php artisan config:clear
```